# How do i create a new column that categories the data into two values based on the integer (Python)

Tags: python

I am having difficulties in solving this error.

There is a column Size1 with size values ranging from 0, 1, 51, 201, 501, 1001, 5001, 10001

I am trying create a new column that splits the data into two string which is "1-1001" and "1001+"

I tried was

```
if fourthcycle_df["Size1"] <= 1001:
    fourthcycle_df["NewSize"]  = "1-1001"
else:
    fourthcycle_df["NewSize"]  = "1001+"
        
fourthcycle_df
```

but they gave me an error which was

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Comment: `fourthcycle_df["Size1"]` is a vector that contains several elements. You are checking if they are `<=1001`, so the result will be that some might be `<= 1001` and some might be `> 1001`. The program is asking you: What do you want to do: Apply the action if `all` values are `<=1001`  or if `any` of the values are `<=1001`. So you have to decide and use one of the options provided in the error message

Answer (score 0):

You can use :

```
fourthcycle_df["NewSize"] = ["1-1001" if x<=1001 else "1001+" for x in fourthcycle_df["Size1"]]
```